# "Ударить по двери" или "ударить в дверь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Как правильно сказать: *ударить по двери* или *ударить в дверь*?

Comment: Произношение — это, можно сказать, способ прочтения одного и того же слова или текста. В данном вопросе  слово *произношение* употреблено неверно, так как речь идет об изменении падежа.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианты верны, но, как мне кажется, у них р**азные семантические оттенки.**

**Ударить в дверь ногой.**

В.п. обозначает действие, направленное на предмет. В этом случае "дверь" находится в центре внимания (также возможно, что это более сильный удар), а орудие действия "ногой"  на втором плане.

**Ударить по двери ногой.**

Здесь всё наоборот: П.п. (по двери) только обозначает предмет, по которому ударили, а форма "ногой" находится на первом плане.

Answer (score 0):

Словарь допускает оба варианта (ударить во что и ударить по чему):

> [УДАРИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), -рю, -ришь; ударенный; -рен, -а, -о; св. 1. во что, обо что, по чему. Произвести удар, стукнуть. У. кулаком, ногой. У. молотком, палкой, рукой. У. по гвоздю, по столу. Резко у. в дверь. У. изо всей силы

Примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка:

> Хозяйка, решив, что ее не пускают, ударила **по двери** ногой. [Борис Поздняков. Переходящее красное знамя // «Сибирские огни», 2012]
>
> Чеченка несколько раз ударила **по двери** кулаком, что-то прокричала – и тут же раздался мощный взрыв. [Павел Евдокимов. Удар «черной вдовы» (2003) // «Спецназ России», 2003.06.15]
>
> Королев два раза ударил **в дверь** локтем. [Александр Иличевский. Матисс // «Новый Мир», 2007]
>
> Звонок не работал, и я несколько раз ударил **в дверь** ногой. [Евгений Прошкин. Механика вечности (2001)]

Я бы употреблял *ударить в дверь* в смысле *громко постучать в дверь*, а *ударить по двери*, если просто действие направлено на дверь.